# Add NTFS access from CSV

Tags: powershell

I try to add NTFS access to the shortcuts.
I have the csv file that contains:

> ```
> Name,AD
> Steps Recorder.lnk,Group_312312
> Snipping Tool.lnk,Group_545345
> ```

```
$FolderPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\"
$file = "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\Group.csv"
$groups = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Csv
 foreach ($group in $groups){ 
    Add-NTFSAccess -Path (Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath ($group.Name+".lnk")) `
                   -Account $group.AD `
                   -AccessRights ReadAndExecute `
    }
```

So, I have the error:

> Add-NTFSAccess : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'Steps Recorder.lnk'.

How can I get -Path parameter from $FolderPath and name of shortcut from csv file?

Comment: I can add full path to csv file, but need to do in this way.

Comment: Change `$FolderPath+$group.Name` into `(Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath $group.Name)`

Comment: above your Add-NTFSAccess command, do `$abc = $FolderPath+$group.Name` and then Add-NTFSAccess $abc -account .... etc.`

Comment: @Theo One more question, how to modify the script? Need to find *.lnk files recurse in $FolderPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\"

Comment: @юра Then look up `Get-ChildItem` with parameters `Recurse` and `Filter`

Comment: @Theo I know this command :). Could you please take a look at the script above? I have a lot of subfolders with *.lnk files in $FolderPath. But in this way, the scripts find only in $FolderPath without subfolders. How can I change the script to find all *.lnk files include subfolders?